# Django Foreign Key query_set update through Views.py

Tags: django, database, sqlite, django-models

As an extension of the polling app tutorial from the Django docs, I'm creating user profiles and I want to grab a particular user's response to each question and store it in the database, and be able to list all the responses of a user to all the questions when the user signs in. And also all responses to a question from all the users. The tutorial creates two models : Question and Choice.(Choice has Question as ForeignKey). But how do I attach a particular question's choice selected by a particular user, to that same User?

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    uzers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date > timezone.now()


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class Response(models.Model):
    uzer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    response = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uzer + self.question + self.response



datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

views.py :

```
from .models import Choice, Question, Response

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:

        selected_choice.votes += 1
        q = selected_choice.question
        c = selected_choice
        r= Response(uzer=User, question = q,response =c )
        r.save()

        #User.response_set(question = selected_choice.question, response = selected_choice )
        selected_choice.save()
        User.save()


        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

I also tried :
     User.response_set.create(question = q, response = c)
Also tried replacing 'create' with 'add'. Didn't work.

Comment: Why not having a ForeignKey to User and Choice?

Comment: Thanks brett. I should have been clearer. I have edited it for greater clarity.

Comment: So is your question where you get the user from? If yes - you need to have some kind of autorizsation - the easiest would be to use 'django.contrib.auth' and you need to protect your views from accessing them without login (@login_required). Details you can find in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator